# How to append parts of a string in a char array?

Tags: c

I need to split the string of n size and append in an array.

For example:

input:

```
abcdefghi
4
```

output:

```
[abcd,bcde,cdef,defg,efgh,fghi]
```

My code giving wrong answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char str[] = "abcdefghi";
  char result[100]; 
  for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){
    strncat(result, str, str[i]+4);
  }
  printf("result: %s\n ", result);
}
```

My output:

```
abcdefgiabcdefgiabcdefgiabcdefgiabcdefgiabcdefgiabcdefgiabcdefgi
```

What mistake have I made??

Comment: What exactly are your parameters to `strncat` supposed to mean? How is `str[i]+4` gonna be a useful value for length?

Comment: Your example output is not splitting the string at all. It extracts substrings of length 4.

Comment: regarding: `for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){`    variable `i` is an integer and the returned value from `strlen()` is a `size_t`.  the code goes downhill from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might this work for you?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] = "abcdefghijklmno";
  char result[100][100]; 
  int nSplit = 4; //Split size
  int nLength = strlen (str); //Lenth of the string
  int nTotalString = nLength - nSplit; //total possibilities
  
  int nStrCount = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i <= nTotalString ; i ++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < nSplit; j++)
           result[nStrCount][j] = str[i + j];
        nStrCount++;
    }
    
  //print array
  printf ("result:[");
  for (int k = 0; k < nStrCount; k++)
    printf ("\"%s\" ", result[k]);
  printf ("]");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Would you please try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "abcdefghi";
    char result[100];
    int n = 4;
    int i, j;
    char *p = result;                                   // pointer to the string to write the result

    *p++ = '[';                                         // left bracket
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str) - n + 1; i++) {         // scan over "str"
        for (j = i; j < i + n; j++) {                   // each substrings
            *p++ = str[j];                              // write the character
        }
        *p++ = i == strlen(str) - n ? ']' : ',';        // write right bracket or a comma
    }
    *p++ = '\0';                                        // terminate the string with a null character
    printf("result: %s\n", result);                     // show the result
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
result: [abcd,bcde,cdef,defg,efgh,fghi]
```